# Why does pgfkeys say that it doesn't know the key?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am facing an error message such as

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/cvGreenLight'
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
\fill[cvGreenLight]"
```

while using the below lines.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[cvGreenLight] (current page.north west) 
    rectangle ++(\cvSideWidth+2\cvMargin,-\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where is `cvGreenLight` defined, and `\cvSideWidth` etc?

Answer (score 2):

The code shown has an undefined color (which generates the error shown) and two undefined lengths. Defining them allows it to run without error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,matrix}
\definecolor{cvGreenLight}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\newlength\cvSideWidth \setlength\cvSideWidth{5cm}
\newlength\cvMargin \setlength\cvMargin{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[cvGreenLight] (current page.north west) 
    rectangle ++(\cvSideWidth+2\cvMargin,-\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```